# is the logo set in stone yet?

Tags: discussion, design

I have a few font type that may be nice for the logo 
[image: This is Woodbadge font type woodbadge is the highest ADULT award in BSA) and my personal Favorite for this issue]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12):

To my tastes these fonts are old fashioned and cartoon-like. I would prefer something cleaner using cool colours - for me that would be more evocative of the great outdoors.

Answer (score 6):

We can start discussing it now, we certainly should at some time before we leave public beta.  Just know that we will be using this theme (which all betas share) until we are near launch.

Once we are near release, we will be visited by Jin, the Stack Exchange designer, to create and [present to us](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy) a theme he creates for us aided by our [design discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/554/what-should-our-logo-and-design-look-like-once-we-are-no-longer-in-beta).  We will then give him some feedback and after about a week, we'll [get our new design](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/989/new-design-launched) and leave beta.